# Print lines where first field has only four characters using regex in awk?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, regular-expression

```
John Goldenrod:(916) 348-4278:250:100:175

Chet Main:(510) 548-5258:50:95:135

Tom Savage:(408) 926-3456:250:168:200

Elizabeth Stachelin:(916) 440-1763:175:75:300
```

output should contain the lines containing names with only four characters
(john,chet) :

```
awk '$1 ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]" "/ {print}' file
```

this doesn't seem to work for me.
can i do it without using any of the awk functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fields in awk are per default delimited by "", this means `$1` doesn't contain a space, so the correct regex for `$1` is:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/ {print}' file
```

If you want to keep your original approach you can also just use `$0` instead, i.e:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\s/ {print}' file
```

To simplify things you can also use `\w` instead of explicitly defining word characters, i.e:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^\w{4}\s/ {print}' file
```

If you only want to match the space and not something else like `TAB` you just have to replace `\s` with "" (without the quotation marks).

Another issue with your original approach are the missing anchors. As you didn't specify either `^` nor `$` your pattern can occur anywhere, i.e the pattern would match for `Elizabeth Stachelin` with `beth`.

Answer (score 3):

In AWK, you can use regular expression as a *pattern* like `BEGIN` or `END` you often see in AWK script. A simplified code can be like

```
awk '/^[[:alnum:]]{4}\>/'
```

This is all you need to meet you needs. You do not need an *action*, `{print}` is the default action when a patten matched, which prints the entire record, i.e. the entire line.

`[:alnum:]` is a synonym to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` basically, depending on locale. You can also use `\w`—only it also includes underscore `_`, it's a shorthand of `[[:alnum:]_]`:

```
awk '/^\w{4}\>/'
```

`\>` matches the end of a word. By using it, you can match string like `John:(###)...` correctly, if you have records which do not contain the full names.

Although you are asking AWK, but I would suggest using `sed`, it runs almost twice as fast as AWK in the case:

```
sed -n '/^[[:alnum:]]\{4\}\b/p'
```

`\b` is `\>` or `\<` in AWK. I tested on a 500K lines, 100K lines matched, AWK took around 1.7 seconds, sed only took 0.9 seconds. But the test case is extreme, it's just a nitpick suggestion.

I would also suggest you read `man 7 regex` as well as `man awk` and `info awk`.

Answer (score 1):

The first field is `$1`, and its length is `length($1)`, so:

```
awk 'length($1) == 4 {print}'
```

or more succintly

```
awk 'length($1) == 4'
```

What you wrote doesn't work for two reasons. First, you have an extra `" "` in your regexp, so you're requiring that the fields contains double quote, space, double quote. If you fix that, you get `/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]/`, which matches a field that contains at least four ASCII letters or digits, but may contain more, so it will match `Elizabeth` as well as `John`, but not `Tom`. You can write `/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]$/` to anchor the regexp at the start and end, but if what you're after is the *length* of the field, just write that.